# Why do my images display differently in mobile?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am showing 3 rows of images. Here is the `html`:

```
   <div class="glass">
        <div class="image">
            <div>
                <img src="..." />
                <img src="..." />
                <img src="..." />
                <img src="..." />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="..." />
                <img src="..." />
                <img src="..." />
                <img src="..." />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="..." />
                <img src="..." />
                <img src="..." />
                <img src="..." />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.glass .image {
  margin-top: 75px;
}
.glass .image > div {
  display: flex;
}
.glass .image > div > img {
  border: 3px solid #4A4A4A;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}
```

On a desktop view, they are all full width, and I have to scroll to the left to be able to see all the images.

On mobile, they are all forced into a single page view.  You can see all the images without scrolling at all.

I don't know if this changes anything, but I do have this at the top of my `html`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

What am I doing wrong?  How do I make the images horizontally scrollable on mobile?

Comment: Which mobile device are you using?  Not all of them support the unprefixed Flexbox property.

Comment: `iPhone` 6, which I though supported `flexbox`

Comment: No... Safari (desktop or iOS) doesn't support it **unprefixed** until 9.x.

Comment: For compatibility, change "className" to "class" in your tags.

Comment: possible guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Comment: I am testing on an `iPhone` 6 which is running `Safari` 9, so there shouldn't be any issues with the prefixes.